# the confusion of installing locustio

Tags: python

I use `pip install locustio` and being notified that success, but `locust --help` get message `command not found locust`.

and I use `pip list` and get result as below:

```
beautifulsoup4 (4.6.0)
click (6.7)
decorator (4.0.11)
Flask (0.12.2)
gevent (1.2.2)
greenlet (0.4.12)
html5lib (0.999999999)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.9.6)
locustio (0.8)
MarkupSafe (1.0)
msgpack-python (0.4.8)
oauthlib (2.0.2)
pip (9.0.1)
Pygments (2.2.0)
pyzmq (16.0.2)
requests (2.14.2)
requests-oauthlib (0.8.0)
robotframework (3.0.2)
robotframework-extendedrequestslibrary (0.5.5)
robotframework-requests (0.4.7)
robotframework-ride (1.5.2.1)
robotframework-selenium2library (1.8.0)
selenium (3.4.1)
setuptools (28.8.0)
six (1.10.0)
webencodings (0.5.1)
Werkzeug (0.12.2)
wxPython (2.8.12.1)
wxPython-common (2.8.12.1)
```

You can see that `locustio` has been installed. But why I can not use it properly ?

Anyone can give some advice?

Comment: the key point is that i do not know how to target the root cause?

Comment: are you using a virtualenv?